# Replace placeholders on page from within itself

Tags: jquery, html

have a template page that has to be repopulated with values from data source. I wonder how to do it. Excerpt of the page html:
...

```
<td colspan="2">
<strong>QUOTATION [ID]</strong><br>
[Organisation_Details]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<b>Client:</b><br>
[Client]<br>
```

...

So I have to replace [ID] and [Client] here, what is the best approach to do it?

Comment: Have you tried templating libraries or some JS frameworks?

Comment: you can use simple replace function if you know the pattern of your placeholders

Comment: @Justinas I have a page that build these kind of template pages too, I don't know how those libraries can fit in, but I am up for everything that can help and make this more easier

Comment: @NegiRox can you just give me an example, please?

Comment: If you have e.g. PHP that builds it, why not directly output values? Else check this link: https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/

Comment: I have php on that server, but that is not the idea, page is html with data as json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below example. to fill place holders.

```js
var d=document.getElementById('dataToChange').innerText;
    var placeHolders=['[ID]','[Organisation_Details]','[Client]'];
    var valuesForplaceHolders=[1,'Google','youTube'];
    for(var i=0;i<placeHolders.length;i++){
      d=d.replace(placeHolders[i],valuesForplaceHolders[i])
    }
    console.log(d)
 document.getElementById('dataToChange').innerText=d;
```

```html
<div id='dataToChange'>
<td colspan="2">
<strong>QUOTATION [ID]</strong><br>
[Organisation_Details]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<b>Client:</b><br>
[Client]<br></div>
```

Comment: but I want to replace values from the page itself not from a variable. For ie. you have a page with html code + placeholders and then you run script that will change that placeholders.

Comment: you can read that page and store it in variable. or you are trying to say something else

Comment: so page is itself contained, it will be opened and run with a parameter, then it will call db and fetch data to use to replace those placeholders on itself, sure it could be done, don;t you think? thanks

Comment: aha, that was I thinking about too, but what with nested elements?... then I should use body element and instead innerText use innerHTML, do you think it would work?...surely first fix the tables, because they will add rows etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189397/discussion-between-negi-rox-and-dejan-dozet).

Answer (score -1):

Replace the variables with `<span id="{ID_HERE}"></span>`, and give them their own specific IDs. You can then fill those with values using basic JS.

However, I highly suggest you use a templating library, such as [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: That is not so  bad idea, I have to change my template editor first, let us see if someone have idea closest to my initial approach and if not, I will try with this one, thanks.